# How do I establish needed permissions from a list of tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am about to conduct an [Analytics on AWS](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/44c91c21-a6a4-4b56-bd95-56bd443aa449/en-US) workshop. 
I am providing users with AWS accounts linked to our main account.

**Is there a convenient way to somehow derive a list of all Permissions, needed by the users to perform the workshop?** 
(This way I avoid assigning permissions that are too broad)

- This is a broader question, and a recurring theme :
  The only way I found is to painstakingly do a trial and error on a user that is highly restricted and open permissions one by one progressively while I go through the steps of the workshop and see which permission errors pop up.
- This approach is highly inefficient honestly, so I was wondering if there is **a better way to assess this** and come up with some policy that encompasses everything needed to perform such workshops, or maybe there is some templates to start up from, that could ease life a bit.

Comment: That specific workshop [pre-requisites](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/44c91c21-a6a4-4b56-bd95-56bd443aa449/en-US/lab-guide/ingest) states "You need to have access to an AWS account with AdminstratorAccess" so, outside of trial and error, I don't think you will find what you're looking for, unfortunately. I think your concern is well-placed, however.

Comment: IAM Access Analyzer policy generation can be used to assist you in generating the necessary policies based on your user/role activity.